# Vue.js, render one project into another

Tags: vue.js, iframe

I have two projects, localhost:8080 and localhost:8081

I need render second page inside first project, and use something like this

in **routes.js**

```
{
   name:'someThing',
   path: 'someThing',
   component: something,
   props: { source: 'localhost:8081' }
}
```

**something.vue**

```
<template>
    <iframe
        :src="source"
        :style="{ width: '100%', height: '99%', border: 0, overflow: hidden,  margin:0, padding: 0 }"
    >
    </iframe>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'something',
    props: {
        source: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Is it normal? Or I should use slot may be

Comment: What is the exact problem you have?

Comment: I dont know, how to make them both working just on localhost:8080.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.